# How to get Year-Week format in ISO calendar format?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get the current date in ISO Calendar format as follows alongwith the zero padding on the week?

```
2019/W06
```

I tried the following, but prefer something using `strftime` as it is much easier to read.

```
print(str(datetime.datetime.today().isocalendar()[0]) + '/W' + str(datetime.datetime.today().isocalendar()[1]))
2019/W6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code:

```
print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y/W%V'))
```

> %Y    Year with century as a decimal number.
>
> %V - The ISO 8601 week number of the current year (01 to 53), where
>   week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the current year,
>   and with Monday as the first day of the week.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I think %G is probably more correct than %Y.  If there are 53 weeks in the year week 53 will belong in the previous year even if %Y has incremented

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `strftime`:

If you want the zero padding:

```
datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/W%V")
```

Output:

```
2019/W06
```

If you don't want it:

```
datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/W%-V")
```

Output:

```
2019/W6
```

Note that "%V" returns the week number, and the "-" is what removes the leading zero.